# Navigational Circles in Frankfurt Beamer Theme are cut off / overlap

Tags: beamer, pdftex, compiling

The Navigational Circles in Frankfurt Beamer Theme are cut off for some reason and there is furthermore a white line:

[image]

I do not get this problem if executing with overleaf, only if executing locally. I am using pdflatex and Ubuntu 20.04.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} % Frankfurt
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec. 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Sec. 2}
\section{Sec. 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{blasdblfkj}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- To avoid the overlapping miniframe you could add a tiny bit of space after the headline
- I think the white line you see is a viewer issue. Try a different pdf viewer

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} % Frankfurt
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\vskip0.05cm}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec. 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Sec. 2}
\section{Sec. 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{blasdblfkj}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Update:

The miniframes have now been given a bit more space to avoid them from appearing clipped off, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0d9bf9119e193a0124ab6461b4594c716bdbd159

This should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer

Comment: v3.70 or 3.69 ?

Comment: @albert v3.70. Version 3.69 was already released 3 days ago.

Comment: Strange as on https://github.com/josephwright/beamer I see that 3.69 is release around 30 minutes ago. Maybe a discrepancy between CTAN and GitHub?

Comment: @albert That was just because of a naming mismatch with the tag. v3.69 was really sent to ctan on the 20th (and the github 3.69 release points to a commit from 3 days ago https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/8be8bae53d5cbce03f08b4dee220ec26db023f75)

Comment: I can see hat on CTAN, but it is confusing.